# 'He may need not to ...' or 'He may not need to ...'

Tags: modal-verbs

I am wondering if it is correct to say:

**He may need not to ...**

or should we say

**He may not need to ...**

Comment: Context, please. What are you needing not to mean?

Comment: just *need not* is fine... using *to* with it makes me think twice!

Comment: @MaulikV: _He need not go_ is, as you say, fine; and means _he doesn't have to go_. But as _need_ is functioning as a modal there, it cannot be combined with _may_. These examples involve the non-modal form of _need_ (which behaves like _want_).

Answer (score 3):

They are both grammatical and reasonably idiomatic, and have very different meanings.

> He may not need to go.

means "It is possible that he will not have to go".

> He may need not to go.

(which is probably less common) means something like "It is possible that he will find that he must not go."